# DocumentProvider without IFile in eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I have a simple code editor that edits some source file, but the editor must be able to edit a section of the source file. I mean it must be able to work with text input (input stream, or string, or something like that). The problem is I haven't found a DocumentProvider that does not need an IFile reference. I have been googling but I didn't find anything useful. Are there any classes that take care of this, or I have implement it all alone? And if I do can you please share some good literature that will guide me? Thank you very much for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at using StorageDocumentProvider which works with IStorage instead of IFile.  IStorage is probably a better fit for your program-supplied content.

Comment: looks good, i will try it and let you now how it works, thanks.